# Google Sheets Formula To Get Top 10 Values Of Different Segments

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet having 4 columns as

```
**A**  **B**  **ID**    **Cost**   
France  101 1   2,038.67
France  101 2   1,067.87
France  101 3   884.08
France  101 4   872.92
France  101 5   842.53
France  101 6   717.75
France  101 7   409.96
France  101 8   374.00
France  101 9   280.97
France  101 10  232.74
France  101 11  217.16
France  101 12  5.09
India   102 13  52,113.35
India   102 14  34,213.21
India   102 15  24,332.05
India   102 16  23,824.82
India   102 17  21,239.98
India   102 18  18,528.92
India   102 19  12,207.84
India   102 20  11,992.45
India   102 21  10,705.70
India   102 22  6,799.04
India   102 23  6,625.35
India   102 24  6,495.47
India   102 25  6,410.21
```

Now, I am looking for a formula to get top 5 values from Col 4 (cost) segmented by Col A

For ex, the final output should be like:

```
France  101 1   2,038.67
France  101 2   1,067.87
France  101 3   884.08
France  101 4   872.92
France  101 5   842.53
India   102 13  52,113.35
India   102 14  34,213.21
India   102 15  24,332.05
India   102 16  23,824.82
India   102 17  21,239.98
```

I belive this can be done by using Query and Limit formula, But i am unable to use LIMIT for segmenting on criteria basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach **`(not query-based)`** :*

```js
=reduce(A1:D1,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,array_constrain(filter(A:D,A:A=c),5,4))))
```

- *`array_constrain` is used here to set the **limit** as `5 rows * 4 columns` which you may change accordingly*

[image]

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for, Merci Beaucoup!!! I wasted hours searching for the right solution but got it in a jiffy!!!

Answer (score 0):

If data pre-sorted as in the sample, you could use xlookup:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(colA,tocol(A2:A,1),seq,sequence(rows(colA)),
filter(A2:index(D2:D,rows(colA)),(seq-xlookup(colA,colA,seq))<5)))
```

[image]

For a query, you could try:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A1:D,xlookup(A1:A,A1:A,C1:C)},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col1 is not null and Col3-Col5<5",1))
```